# Print the Lua table and connect the strings

Tags: lua

I want to print the table, more complex. like this:

I don't know how to check each value in the table that equals and connects string like this `(value1, value2, value3, and value4)` Before it ends, it must end with `and`

Table:

```
table = {
 {amount = 1, items = "item1"},
 {amount = 1, items = "item2"},
 {amount = 1, items = "item3"},
 {amount = 2, items = "item4"},
 {amount = 3, items = "item5"},
}
```

P.S I need to sort them too.
`table.sort(table, function(a,b) return a.amount < b.amount end)`

but I am still stuck with connect string that I mentioned above.

I want it to output like this:

```
3x item5
2x item4
1x item1, item2, and item3
```

Thanks for the answers, I newbie to Lua, and English is not my native language. Sorry for the incorrect grammar and words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is something like this, only without the output of `and` between `item2, and item3` :

```
local t = {
 {amount = 1, items = "item1"},
 {amount = 1, items = "item2"},
 {amount = 1, items = "item3"},
 {amount = 2, items = "item4"},
 {amount = 3, items = "item5"},
}

local res = {}

for k,v in pairs(t) do
   res[v.amount] = res[v.amount] and (res[v.amount] .. ', ' .. v.items) or v.items  -- use ternary operator   
end 

for k,v in pairs(res) do 
   v = v:gsub("(.*), (.-)","%1 and %2")
   print(k,v)
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to add ```and``` before ```,```?

e.x.
  ```amount = amount``` then push to array to find max index 
```a = {"item1", "item2", "item3"}```

and push ```and``` with:
```a[3] = string.format("%s", "and "..a[3])```

before add ```,``` (comma) by ```table.concat```

Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @GinglrBell I found a slightly different solution how to replace the comma at the end with `and` , provided that the number of words is not known, answer updated